# Bullets aren't showing up in Space Invaders-like game

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I have just started making a game that is going to be somewhat like space invaders.

I'm a complete novice when it comes to programming and have little experience (I'm only attempting this as I need to have a software design project due at the end of next week).

Anyways, I have been following a [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bytt-enP2yU&feature=related) on how to fire bullets. and it doesn't seem to be working. I have copied almost every aspect of this tutorial except for the 'velocity' variable in the 'bullets' class (which I don't think I need as I'm only using side to side movement not forward/back).

This is the code below. Thanks in advance. :)

---

**Main**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Software_Design_Major_Project
{

    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        Texture2D ship; // Declaring the sprite
        Vector2 shipposition = Vector2.Zero; 

        List<bullets> bullets = new List<bullets>();
        KeyboardState pastkey;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 600; 


        }



        protected override void Initialize()
        {

            base.Initialize();
        }


        protected override void LoadContent()
        {

            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            ship = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ship"); // Loads the ship into the memory.
            shipposition = new Vector2((graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2) -
            (ship.Width / 2), 420);


        }


        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {

        }


        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {

            if (Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) && shipposition.X
            >= 0) 
            {
                shipposition.X -= 6;
            }
            if(Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) && shipposition.X <
            ((graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width) - (ship.Width))) 
            {
                shipposition.X += 6;
            }

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && pastkey.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space)) 
            {
                shoot();                
            }
            pastkey = Keyboard.GetState();
            updatebullets();
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        public void updatebullets() 
        {
            foreach(bullets bullet in bullets)
            {

                if (Vector2.Distance(bullet.position, shipposition) < 0)
                    bullet.isvisible = false;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Count; i++) 
            {
                if (!bullets[i].isvisible)
                    bullets.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }
        }

        public void shoot() 
        {
            bullets newbullet = new bullets(Content.Load<Texture2D>("bullet"));
            newbullet.position = shipposition;
            newbullet.isvisible = true;

            if (bullets.Count < 20)
                bullets.Add(newbullet);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend); 
            spriteBatch.Draw(ship, shipposition, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();

            foreach (bullets bullet in bullets)
                bullet.Draw(spriteBatch);

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }



    }
}
```

---

**Bullets**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Software_Design_Major_Project
{

          class bullets // A new class needs to be created to allow for bullets.
        {
            public Texture2D texture;

            public Vector2 position;
            public Vector2 origin;

            public bool isvisible;

            public bullets(Texture2D newtexture) 
            {
                texture = newtexture;
                isvisible = false;
            }

            public void Draw(SpriteBatch spritebatch) 
            {
                spritebatch.Draw(texture, position, null, Color.White, 0f, origin, 1f, 
                SpriteEffects.None, 0);
            }
    }
}
```

P.S. Sorry for the long post.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! Consider a more descriptive title to your question. Most people who come here need assistance in one way or another. Make people understand what _you_ are having a problem with. =)

Comment: Also consider having your actual question clearly defined and easy to find. In this case, "doesn't seem to work" is the only hint I can find that you're having problems. How doesn't it work? What doesn't work? What do you expect should happen?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the XNA sample available [here](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/spacewar)?

Comment: Wouldn't `velocity` be important to tell the bullets how to move?  Regardless of whether you're doing 2D or 3D movement, velocity would be the change in position over a period of time.  Without that, the bullets would just sit there.

Comment: Haha is there any way to edit the title? sorry its a little late over here, didn't proof read my question. umm, well from what I saw of the tutorial after the guy finishes the tutorial he is able to shoot without a problem. I have managed to make make my spaceship sprite to move with the arrow keys, however when i press space to shoot, no bullets show up and i am then unable to move the ship.

Comment: Press edit? Right below the tags

Comment: Im not too sure galactic (im only using 1D movement). thanks cyral

Comment: Basically, you need to zero-out any dimension you're not using, but the other vectors will still be important.  Think of your screen like a sheet of graph paper.  Every location on screen has a unique "address", and to move something somewhere else on the screen you need to update its address.

Comment: Ok thanks :) I'm gunna have to go to bed now. thanks all for the swift responses. Ill come back and try out the suggestions i have tomorrow

Comment: sooo i found another tutorial, but when i debug the game freezes as it did before and im getting an error message highlighting          
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
saying "begin must be called successfully before a draw can be called."

Comment: figured it out :) all i needed to was put spriteBatch.Begin();/End(); on either side of this code.

Comment: The `i--;` in your for loop is a potential (*very likely) infinite loop waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any code that changes your bullets position, Your going to need a velocity variable, and update the position based on the velocity each frame.

And you could get the angle from a = Math.Atan(Y,X)

Looks like you probably removed the part that calculates position, as you thought you didn't need the velocity stuff. I suggest you try adding it back to see if it works, and then removing parts you don't need.

Comment: I put that velocity stuff back in but im still getting the same problem D:

Answer (score 1):

Surprised nobody spotted this sooner.
You're ending your SpriteBatch before the bullets have been drawn.
Calls to SpriteBatch.Draw must occur between the Begin and End methods because of all the work that goes on behind the scenes to make drawing as fast as possible.
All you need to do is move spriteBatch.End() further down, like so:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
        spriteBatch.Draw(ship, shipposition, Color.White);

        foreach (bullets bullet in bullets)
            bullet.Draw(spriteBatch);

        spriteBatch.End(); //Move to here instead

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Extra Trivia:
Basically what goes on behind the scenes is that the sprite batch actually batches up the textures using the settings described by begin (yes, these can be changed) and then when end is called, it figures out which bits fall outside the screen and makes note not to draw them, it depth sorts the textures if told to and it does all sorts of other optimisations before drawing them to the back buffer and then finally when all drawing is over, the back buffer gets presented to the screen and the old one is taken and reused for the next draw call. It sounds like a lot of work, but with the way modern computers work, the optimisations tend to create a big improvement.

Answer (score 0):

you could check this sample right here. I've coded this stuff a long time ago, I think in v2.0 of XNA, can't rembember now.

http://gozoomin.com/media/p/69699.aspx

The logic in there is quit simple :)

Starting making a 'classic' is always a good way to start.

Edit - You can get it here as well: http://www.sendspace.com/file/r4s4um
Edit2 - I just checked the code now, it's with some comments documenting most of things, probably you will get some stuff written in portuguese. 
PS - Don't copy past the code! Try to learn the basics around the sample.